# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Permission denied to access property '__qosId'

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, outlook, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to automate mail sending in Microsoft Outlook/Hotmail, Firefox Webdriver works fine till login after that its constantly throwing exception org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Permission denied to access property '__qosId'. I tried clicking on other elements but its throwing same exception. I clicked on compose (New) button using Jscript but after that the same exception is thrown when i try to click other elements.

**Scenario**

Step 1 - I am getting outlook page through driver.get("https://www.outlook.com"

Step 2 - I am Entering Username And Password through sendKeys

Step 3 - Clicking Login Button. Login Completes

Step 4 - I am trying to Click Compose/new button

Here I am getting that exception.. I tried clicking on other elements but same exception is thrown. I Clicked Compose button with Jscript it clicked but as i try to enter To email address with sendKeys again same exception is thrown. My Code Works Fine With Latest Versions Of IE and Chrome. I am Attaching my code and stack trace please have a look and help me out.

I tried with Firefox version 27,28 & 30. Initially i was trying with Firefox 30 then tried with 28 & 27 but still the same exception.

Comment: Could you please update your test page HTML, source code as well as exception stacktrace?

Comment: Here are the links of Sample HTML, Source Code and Exception Stacktrace.                        https://www.sendspace.com/file/9liq99 
https://www.sendspace.com/file/2pk3mu 
https://www.sendspace.com/file/6dte6k

Comment: By re-run your script many times on my machine but I am not able to get any exception. When I run it on a slower machine, after login, I get stuck in a blank page for a while -> then getting NoSuchElementException. Are you able to get the view with Compose button? Have you tried in debug mode and run step by step?

Comment: Yeah its in view only. I even clicked compose with Jscript. I tried on other systems but still exception was thrown, yeah i debugged it step by step but same exception is thrown.Below is the stacktrace while debugging. Permission denied to access property '__qosId'
Command duration or timeout: 275 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.42.0', revision: '5e82430', time: '2014-05-22 20:18:33'
System info: host: 'Blr-Floter04', ip: '192.168.238.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_51'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Comment: Versions - Selenium version:2.42.0
Jave: 1.7
OS:Windows 7
Browser:Firefox
Browser version:27,28,29,30. Which version of firefox you are using? I got this exception in 30 and then in 27 & 28.

Comment: I even raised same issue in official selenium bug tracker forum... and they got same exception so they accepted the issue.. just search it.. issue no is-7588

Comment: Any Update.. i am still stuck on that issue..

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing with doesn't have a direct fix with it, but you could use some workarounds,

1. Try to set the preferences something like this,

> setPreference("capability.policy.default.Window.frameElement.get","allAccess");

1. Set the website as Trusted site or to the Exceptional sites list in firefox settings

And also you could look at the link for some insight [#Firefox issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2863)

Comment: I tried it already.. I tried all this..                FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("capability.policy.default.Window.QueryInterface", "allAccess");  
profile.setPreference("capability.policy.default.Window.frameElement.get","allAccess");
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);  profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);                       DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities(); capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true); driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

Comment: makesure you try it for the instance that get you the error.

Comment: I could't get you.. there is only one instance.. its works fine til login after that it throws exception.. I tried to click different elements but no use..

Answer (score 0):

Old question , I know, but I started to get this on Firefox v 75 and Selenium 3.14.

It was working before.

I found though that if I open another FireFox window then run the app the error goes away.